# How to show user posted blog in user profile page as a my post list section in Django 3?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I am a new Django learner. I have created a blog website with two apps blog and user. In the user app, I have created a user profile page with two section user basic information and my post list. When user login and visit his/her profile page, my post list section shows only this user published post else shows you have not published any post yet. Everything is working fine but my post list section shows all of the posts in the blog. I want to show only this user's post, not other users' posts. I think the queryset in the view section needs to be modified but I cannot understand what would be. Here is my code -

#Blog App: Post Model

```
   class Post(models.Model):
          title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
          slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
          author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
          updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
          content = models.TextField()
          created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
          
          class Meta:
              ordering = ['-created_on']

         def __str__(self):
              return self.title
```

#User App: Profile Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pic = models.ImageField(default='images/default.jpg', upload_to='images')
    about = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

#User App: views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from blog.models import Post

class UserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
     queryset = Post.objects.all()
     template_name = "profile.html"
```

#My Post Lists Section in profile.html page

```
<div class="user-post-list mt-4">
                    <h4>My Post Lists</h4>
                    <div class="table-responsive mt-4 mb-5">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="text-left">
                                    <th>TITLE</th>
                                    <th>CREATED ON</th>
                                    <th>UPDATED ON</th>
                                    <th>EDIT</th>
                                    <th>DELETE</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {% for post in post_list %}
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ post.slug }} </td>
                                    <td>{{ post.created_on }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.updated_on }}</td>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="#" role="button">Edit</a></td>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            {% endfor%}
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle user's id from url to your view by `self.kwargs['user_id']` and filter his post by `Post.objects.filter(author=self.kwargs['user_id'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I solve it. Just need to define queryset.

```
class UserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
 #queryset = Post.objects.all()
 template_name = "profile.html"

 def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return Post.objects.filter(author=user)
```