# How to show documents uploaded by specific users only in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm a newcomer to django and I'm trying to create a user system where different users can log in and upload and view their documents. The upload and viewing works except users are able to see each others documents as well. How can I make it so that users are only able to see documents uploaded by them?

The following question also talk about the same problem but I'm unable to understand how the issue was fixed: [How to show user posted blog in user profile page as a my post list section in Django 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767371/how-to-show-user-posted-blog-in-user-profile-page-as-a-my-post-list-section-in-d/74595059#74595059)

I realize I've to use foreign keys in my models but I'm not sure how to implement it. Here's snippets of my code so far:

Edit: Removed code due to copyright. For all those who helped, thanks a ton. Your answers were immeasurably helpful.

Comment: I noticed that the default value for your user foreign key field is 1.  This will make the user for all documents default to the one that has the id 1, which might be the first one who signs up, or it might not exist at all.  I would erase the default value here so that it gets left as null by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display to user only documents created by request user, you can filter your Document queryset by user ForeignKey:

```
# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.filter(user=request.user)

# Render list page with the documents and the form
context = {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'message': message}
return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

This way, you are excluding non user documents on DB level, which is much faster than iterating over every single document and checking if user is matching to request user

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working either. I think the document isn't getting linked to the user in the starting part of the view function itself(?). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the top of your view, check that the user is authenticated. Otherwise, setting the user might fail silently